# How to use google protocol buffers with java me?

Tags: java-me, protocol-buffers

i have designed a protocol using google protocol buffers and now want to write a java me client. but [this](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-javame/) implementation that i have found is severely restricted. it does not allow enums, nested messages and is very basic which defeats the purpose of using it.

is there an alternative implementation of protocol buffers for java-me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm... I didn't know that the java-me story was lacking; you might want to ask on the [specific group](http://groups.google.com/group/protobuf). The [3rd party page](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns) lists [one other](http://swingme.sourceforge.net/encode.shtml) that might be worth a look.

Of course, you could write your own ;-p (and yes: I realise that defeats the purpose even further; I'm half in jest here... nearly half...)